Cannot Reference WinUI 3 Community Toolkit In .Net 9 Application
Big project is converting UWP app to WinUI3.  The UWP app uses the UWP Toolkit for the Grid Splitter control.  Trying to reference the CommunityToolkit in WINUI + .Net 9 I can choose Nuget Package CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Controls.Sizers.  However I cannot reference this package in XAML
xmlns:toolSizer="using:CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Controls.Sizers"

All the samples use
xmlns:toolSizer="using:CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Controls"

but this does not work either.  I have read mountains of documentation and not sure what I am doing wrong.

I have package CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Controls.Sizers (8.1.240916) in the Depencencies\Packages folder for the project

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Reading more documentation I changed Target Framework - net9.0-windows10.0.22621.0  and Unloaded and then Reloaded the project and it appeared to fix the issue with my small tester app.  I will try it in my large app and see if it gets rid of the issue.

This is mentioned in the release notes. You need to update your target versions to 22621:
<TargetFramework>net9.0-windows10.0.22621.0</TargetFramework>
<WindowsSdkPackageVersion>10.0.22621.38</WindowsSdkPackageVersion>


Thank you for the response.  I was not aware of the  value I have included that in my project as well.

If this was helpful, please accept it as the answer so we can close this session.
